# MODX Revo: не отправляет письма, даже восстановление пароля админа

Tags: modx, smtp, sendmail, revo

Формы, комментарии с сайта отправляются нормально, в админке видно.
А с почтой беда. Восстановление забытого пароля пользователя через сайт письма не отправляет. Думаю, дело в настройках, ибо даже при входе в админку письмо с паролем не отправляет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В логах ничего интересного:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зато интересно вот что. Настройки почты сделал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в "информации о системе" вижу вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда это взялось и где искать?
Поиск по базе и по файлам на сервере результатов не дал.

Comment: Попробуйте параметр `SMTP хосты` установить в виде: `ssl://smtp.mail.ru`

Comment: Tunker, спасибо, заработало. Только мне не нравится отправитель письма "MODX Revolution spprt.admn@mail.ru". В принципе, мне-то пофиг, а вот пользователь моего сайта, запросивший восстановление пароля, получает так же.Где исправить отправителя? И как теперь тут отметить вопрос решенным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр `SMTP хосты (mail_smtp_hosts)` необходимо установить в виде: `ssl://smtp.mail.ru`

P.S. Вообще для этого существует параметр `SMTP префикс для соединений (mail_smtp_prefix)` который принимает значения: `"", "ssl", "tls"` но в одной из версий modx был баг и префикс не работал, это быстро исправили, но я так и остался на вышеуказанном варианте.